# React-native-navigation check if componentId exists before push

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation library to navigate through screens in my app, the problem is that if I navigate to a screen by pressing a button and press fast multiple times then that particular screen opens multiple times. My question is if it's there any possibility to check if a screen exists in the stack before pushing it, I wonder if exist any method or property from which I can get the stack with the components ids.

PS: I don't want to disable the button after first tap.

Comment: did you get the any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can throttle the function where the button click event is handled. [lodash.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) can be used quite easily for this.